# Can I exclude a path pattern from SwiftPackageManager?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

In SPM I'd like to exclude a folder name from the target but using a pattern that will ignore all folders of that name.

So, if I define a target like this:

```
.target(name: "MyTarget", dependencies: [], exclude: ["*/Resources"]),
```

It would exclude all folders with that name within the `MyTarget` directory tree.

At the moment with the above target defined it is literally looking for a file named `.../MyTarget/*/Resources` and failing to find it. So I realise this is not the correct format. I'm just wondering if this is possible to do at all?

Is it possible to specify a directory? And if so can it pattern match all of them?

Comment: There is a related discussion: https://forums.swift.org/t/support-for-wildcard-paths-in-package-swift/37814